# SwiftUI: Sheet cannot show correct values in first time

Tags: ios, list, swiftui

I found strange behavior in SwiftUI.

The sheet shows empty text when I tap a list column first time.
It seems correct after second time.

Would you help me?

```
import SwiftUI

let fruits: [String] = [
    "Apple",
    "Banana",
    "Orange",
]

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var isShowintSheet = false
    @State var selected: String = ""
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(fruits, id: \.self) { fruit in
                Button(action: {
                    selected = fruit
                    isShowintSheet = true
                }) {
                    Text(fruit)
                }
            }
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $isShowintSheet, content: {
            Text(selected)
        })
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

[list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ivmjE.png)

[first tap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/igN2z.png)

[after second tap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EOPYo.png)

Answer (score 17):

Use `.sheet(item:)` instead. Here is fixed code.

Verified with Xcode 12.1 / iOS 14.1

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var selected: String?
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(fruits, id: \.self) { fruit in
                Button(action: {
                    selected = fruit
                }) {
                    Text(fruit)
                }
            }
        }
        .sheet(item: $selected, content: { item in
            Text(item)
        })
    }
}

extension String: Identifiable {
    public var id: String { self }
}
```

Comment: Does anyone know any technical reason behind this? Regarding the isPresented version.

Answer (score 4):

Thank you, Omid.

I changed my code from Asperi's code using @State like this.

```
import SwiftUI

struct Fruit: Identifiable, Hashable {
    var name: String
    var id = UUID()
}

let fruits: [Fruit] = [
    Fruit(name: "Apple"),
    Fruit(name: "Banana"),
    Fruit(name: "Orange"),
]

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var selected: Fruit?
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(fruits, id: \.self) { fruit in
                Button(action: {
                    selected = fruit
                }) {
                    Text(fruit.name)
                }
            }
        }
        .sheet(item: $selected, content: { item in
            Text(item.name)
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: there is other ways also, but the Answer should be close as much as possible to question! my Answer mach most to topic

Comment: @Omid I'm not sure if that's true. You're using a global variable and `sheet(isPresented:content:)` which is wrong for this example (personally I wouldn't accept your answer). Asperi's solution `sheet(item:content:)` is the correct one. But omusubi's solution with creating a `Fruit` struct is even better (and probably should be the accepted one).