# SwiftUi sheet is blank on first tap but works correctly afterwards

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-ontapgesture

I have a sheet that I put outside a foreach loop . When I click on Tapgesture the first time the results are blank, after the first time I get the correct data for every row I tap . I have read [Sheet inside ForEach doesn't loop over items SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63088893/sheet-inside-foreach-doesnt-loop-over-items-swiftui) but it is still not working this is my code . If you look at my code I have a state variable called **sharePost** which on tap gets the value of **value.post** then the **shareSheet** toggle gets set to true . For some reason I can not get the value on very first tap . Does anyone have any suggestions on fixing this issue

```
struct TimeLineView: View {
    @Binding var model: [MainModel]
    @Binding var isMainView: MainViewEnum
    @State var shareSheet = false
    @State var PostIDState = 0
    @State var sharePost = ""

var body: some View {
        ZStack
        {

         let result = model.sorted {
                        $0.id! > $1.id!
                    }
                    
                    ForEach(result) { value in
                   HStack {
                            Image("share")
                              .resizable()
                              .frame(width: 28, height: 28)
                              .onTapGesture {
                                            sharePost = value.post
                                            shareSheet.toggle()
                     
                                             }

                        }
                    }

                 }.sheet(isPresented: $shareSheet) 
                  {
                     ShareView(message:"\(sharePost)" )
                  }
             }

        }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/64798254/12299030? (possible duplicate)

Comment: Might be related with iOS 14 changes - see [iOS14 introducing errors with @State bindings](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63928736/8697793). What environment do you use?

Comment: Yes it answers my question, thank you. I am using IOS 14 .

Answer (score 10):

To fix this issue, one solution is to implement the sheet modifier in the following way:

```
.sheet(isPresented: Binding(
                get: { shareSheet },
                set: { shareSheet = $0 }
            )) {
                ShareView(message:"\(sharePost)" )
            }
```

Comment: Nice, worked for me! Was trying to not use 'sheet(item' but isPresented was giving me this first attempt problem, this answer works.

Comment: Worked for me when using fullScreenCover!

Comment: Incredible thanks! 
Does this mean the default binding for sheet is simply bugged?

Answer (score 7):

Apparently, one of the workarounds for this is to use `StateObject` instead of `State`. [Here's a Medium article that demonstrates the solution](https://medium.com/swlh/swiftui-sheets-navigation-bars-and-broken-states-312014ed1a3e).

Comment: can confirm this works. Thanks for the link!

Comment: Yes, it works. Obviously a bug in iOS.